# Getting a debounced function to return a variable

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I have a function called `debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage` that I want to return the `scrollPercentage`. As it is debounced, it incorrectly returns `undefined`, presumably because the debounce function  does not return anything.

How can `debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage()` return the `scrollPercentage`, so that `scrolledDownPercentage: debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage()` is not undefined? I assume a global variable accessible to all scopes could solve it, but I would prefer a different solution.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

For context, here is all the code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; }; // for testing, so you can click close and the browser won't close and you can still see the logs

// initial data
let bounced = true;
const sessionStartTime = new Date();
let maxScrollPosition = 0;
let totalScrollDistance = 0;

// functions
const setBouncedToFalse = () => {
  bounced = false;
  document.removeEventListener("click", setBouncedToFalse);
};
const calculateSessionTime = () => {
  const sessionEndTime = new Date();
  return sessionEndTime - sessionStartTime; // sessionTimeMs
}
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};
const debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage = debounce(() => {
// const debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage = debounce((callback) => {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  let scrollPercentage = 0;

  if (scrollPosition > maxScrollPosition) {
    const scrollDistance = scrollPosition - maxScrollPosition;
    totalScrollDistance += scrollDistance;
    maxScrollPosition = scrollPosition;
    const maxPossibleScrollDistance = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    scrollPercentage = Math.round(totalScrollDistance / maxPossibleScrollDistance * 100);
  }

  return scrollPercentage;
  // callback(scrollPercentage);
}, 200);
const processData = () => {
  const userData = {
    sessionTimeMs: calculateSessionTime(),
    bounced,
    scrolledDownPercentage: debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage() // incorrectly returns undefined
  };

  debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage((scrollPercentage) => {
    userData.scrolledDownPercentage = scrollPercentage;
    console.log('userData: ', userData);
  });
}

// events
document.addEventListener("click", setBouncedToFalse); // track clicks (if user bounces)
window.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage); // needed?
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", processData); // process data before user leaves
```

Comment: Well it can't. The function may not execute until later.

Comment: You'll definitely need a global (or at least shared-scope) variable `userData` if you want to fill it from a debounced scroll listener and use it from the beforeunload listener. It makes no sense to call `debouncedGetScrolledDownPercentage()` when the `beforeunload` event fires. The callback approach (which you commented out) doesn't change that.